# TSQL walk a table to find the root ID

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive CTE to find parent records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935005/recursive-cte-to-find-parent-records)

I have a table with a primary key and parent Id that points back to the same table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Things](
    [ThingID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentThingID] [int] NULL, ... )
```

I would like to develop a proc to walk the a provided @ThingId to the root parent ID. My meager TSQL skills are failing me. Please help. T

Comment: @Derek - only if he is using SQL Server 2005+

Comment: @Kenny what version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2008, I'll take a look at the link. T